# WCF returns bad JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a wcf service that must return JSON. My code looks like:

```
public String areaGetStreetTypes(int city_id, int language_id)
        {
            string json = "";
            string responseList = "{\"triname\":\"IMP\",\"name\":\"IMPASSE\"}";
            if (responseList.Length != 0){
                string responseStatusJSON = "{\"status\":0, \"message\":\"Success !!!\"}";
                json += "{\"responseList\":[" + responseList + "],";
                json += "\"responseStatus\":" + responseStatusJSON + "}";
            }
            else{
                string responseStatusJSON = "{\"status\":1, \"message\":\"Error !!!\"}";
                json += responseStatusJSON;
            }
            return json;
        }

//my interface looks like
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "areaGetStreetTypes", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]        
        String areaGetStreetTypes(int city_id, int language_id);
```

Response in raw format:

> {"areaGetStreetTypesResult":"{\"responseList\":[{\"triname\":\"IMP\",\"name\":\"IMPASSE\"}],\"responseStatus\":{\"status\":0, \"message\":\"Success !!!\"}}"}

I use a php script for testing. After first decoding:

> stdClass Object(
>
> ```
> [areaGetStreetTypesResult] => {"responseList":[{"triname":"IMP","name":"IMPASSE"}],"responseStatus":{"status":0, "message":"Success !!!"}}
> ```
>
> )

Only after my second json_decode I get what I want: [GOOD JSON Response](http://pastebin.com/QDUUASma)

What can I change in my service to get the good JSON the first time? I want to decode only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You JSON'ing twice - one time in your method and second when you tell WCF to serialize with JSON in WebInvoke attribute.

Why not make couple more contracts and return them, instead of manually construct result string?

Comment: this is a just a test. i cannot implement a fixed type because i get my data dynamically from db. i don't know the no of columns returned or the name of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class object that can be returned as shown below:

```
namespace Rest
{
    public class JsonRes
    {
        public ResponseList ResponseList { get; set; }
        public ResStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    }
    public class ResponseList
    {
        public string triName { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResStatus
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The WCF framework does the serialization to JSON.

If you have the json String being build dynamically from db then try to find if you can get a generic object that would be enough under all scenarios. Like having a List of object that has the column name and its value and then passing back the complete list back to the client.

Comment: i already have two of your classes. I have Response (responseList, resposeMessage : ResponseStatus) and ResponseStatus(status, message). I will try your approach but i used dictionary and the json returned smething like : "key":"keyName", "value":"valueName" and i wanted "keyName":"valueName".

Comment: Try using a List<object> (make it a typed object) and that would give you something like key:value

Comment: Also another approach would be to create a class dynamically based on the result set you get back from the database and then use this class to be returned by the framework. Going to be a tedious process though. See the link to create a class dynamically (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/abff98e3-93fe-44fa-bfd4-fcfe297dbc43 )